# jquery chart should show ticks labels without data

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have chart like this  [reference links](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/showempty/)
You can switch off series, but without data chart change size. And in my case it souldn't do this. I want to show ticks labels all time or make chart to have fixed plot plase. How can I do this?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        title: {
            text: 'Y axis showEmpty demo'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Left axis shows even if Series 1 is hidden. Right axis does not show when Series 2 is hidden.'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        yAxis: [{
            lineWidth: 2
            // showEmpty: true // by default
        }, {
            lineWidth: 2,
            opposite: true,
            showEmpty: true,
            min:0
        }],

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            yAxis: 0
        }, {
            data: [106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5],
            yAxis: 1,
            visible: false
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is by setting an axis min and max.

See `example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/Lpgxoo0e/

{{ edit to address comments:

Why would you want to set a max when there is no data, and remove it when there is data?
Just find out what the max in your data is, and set it accordingly.

It is not possible to simply "unset" the min and max values - they must be set to something (they are always set to something, whether you choose what that is, or the library chooses...)

What you can do, if you don't want to pre-process your data to get the max, is to set a callback function on your chart call, and make use of the getExtremes() and setExtremes() functions to explicitly set the min/max to the values that Highcharts would naturally use anyway.

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes

In that case, you'll also need to set all series to visible by default, and hide them after you set the axis min/max values.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/Lpgxoo0e/5/

{{edit

Ok, one more:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/oretk9m3/

This uses same function but calls it from the legendItemClick event, which requires a little more complication.

Comment: it work only with **max:** and I cann't use it. I don't know what date will be used.

Comment: If you pre-process your data you should be able to determine a suitable max to use.

Comment: I sould set max only when i have no data and take off whet it is. whow can i do that?

Comment: sorry but it isn't that what i want, I need Yaxes all time on screen. If I have no data label can show values between 0 and 1, but labels on screen should be. And when I set max:1 animation doesn't work when I hide or show series

Comment: "I need Yaxes all time on screen" my example does that. You'll need to give a lot more detail about what you need that my example doesn't provide.  There is no "always show the axes" option that you can set - You *MUST* tell it a min and max to display if you want it to work.

Comment: Can I set max when i hide series?

Comment: You can.  You can use the legendItemClick event: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick  But why???

Comment: But how should I set max? I try in different way, it doesn't work

Comment: Here's the thing: If you set the max when you hide the series, you're still setting the max for when you show the series...or else you have to then set the max to something else when you show the series. So either way, you need to set the min/max for the series when you hide and and when you show the series. I am not understanding why setting the max is something you don't want to do...? It's necessary.

Comment: updated example added to answer, using the legendItemClick event

Comment: It's wery well, thank you, but now i have other issue, can i make tick labels with the same width? If at y Axis write 1000 and when i hide axis, and will write 10 than chart will be deformaded, how can i avoid this?

Comment: You'll have to post an example